# BJT Mode of operation when VBE = VBE(ON)

Tags: bjt

I know that, for a BJT, when VBE < VBE(ON) the transistor is in cut-off, and when VBE > VBE(ON) the transistor is either in linear of forward active depending on VCE, but what about when VBE = VBE(ON)?

Comment: If VBE > VBE(ON), you have a dead transistor, whose base-emitter junction is open. Any VBE greater than about 1v (for silicon transistors) causes too much base current to flow, overheating it.

Answer (score 1):

For a BJT as you say if VBE < VBE(ON) the transistor is in cut-off, when you get to VBE = VBE(ON) the base and the emiter of the transistor behave like a diode, with the voltage drop of a diode (0.6-0.7V) it means you "can't" have more than  VBE = VBE(ON), you only can have the voltage drop across the diode. If you try to increase the VBE you only increase the base current, and you can destroy the transistor.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the VBE(ON) you're talking about is specified in datasheets under specific conditions, you maybe are aware of. Cut-off does not mean that Ic=0A, it is typically in µA region or so.

Likewise, having VBE slightly lower/higher than VBE(ON) will only allow less/more current to flow through the collector.

Answer (score 0):

The voltage across base is a logarithmic function of the current. About 0.058 volts increase, per 10:1 current increase.

Expect 0.4v +-0.1v at 1uA.

Expect 0.058 * 3 (for 3 orders of magnitude) or nearly 0.6 volts at 1mA.
Plus or minus.

Changes 2mv or 2.2 mv per degree Centigrade.